# I need some clarification on the program below. How does the "t" argument affect the program

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

The code works, I just have no idea how the "t" value becomes the number 4 in the second array. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = arr1.concat(arr2);

  function checkit(t) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(t) === -1 || arr2.indexOf(t) === -1) {
      return t;
    }

  }
  return newArr.filter(checkit);
}
diff([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function in its argument.

In your case you are providing the `checkit` method to `filter` where it iterates through `newArr`. For each iteration `t` is the value present in `newArr` where you are basically checking whether `t` is present in both of `arr1` and `arr2` or not. If either of them do not have that element, you are returning back the element.

Here `4` is the value.

To make it more clear, I will break this into steps :

1. `var newArr = arr1.concat(arr2);`
   Here after concat `newArr` becomes `[1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.
2. In the next step `newArr.filter()` method is called.
   As per the `filter()` docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter `filter()` method filters out the elements from the invoked array that passes the required test as per the callback provided. Here the callback or the method is `checkit()`.
3. In the `checkit()` method the `t` represents the value of an element in `newArr`. So in the `if` condition you are checking whether `t` is present in `arr1` and `arr2` or not.
4. Let's take the 1st element of `newArr` as an example. Now 1st element in `newArr` is 1. `arr1.indexOf(1)` would give you zero, because element 1 is present at the zeroth postion of `arr1`. Same happens with `arr2`. Now `arr1.indexOf(1) === -1` would give you false and `arr2.indexOf(1) === -1` would also give you false.
5. It will go on like this until you reach value 4 ie. the second last element in `newArr`. Here when you do `arr1.indexOf(4)`, you will get -1 as the element 4 is not present in the `arr1`. So `arr1.indexOf(1) === -1` would give you true. The `if` condition will get true and the current element `t` ie 4 will be returned.
6. Next as 5 is present in both the arrays the if condition won't get satisfied. Hence you are left with only 4 in your array.